# connection string to read from different databases in C#

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Suppose I want to check data between 2 different systems/databases as below:

```
select    CLIENT1.CLIENTNAME AS CLIENTNAME1,
          CLIENT2.CLIENTNAME AS CLIENTNAME2
from      [System1-Database]..CLIENT as CLIENT1
left join [System2-Database]..CLIENT as CLIENT2
on        CLIENT1.idclient=CLIENT2.idclient
```

The problem is that I have one connection string for each system/database (one using sql-server and the other using oracle).

How can I do to do this select command in c#?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use sp_addlinkedserver to create a server link. See the reference documentation for usage. Once the server link is established, you'll construct the query as normal, just prefixing the database name with the other server. I.E:

```
-- FROM DB1
SELECT *
FROM [MyDatabaseOnDB1].[dbo].[MyTable] tab1
    INNER JOIN [DB2].[MyDatabaseOnDB2].[dbo].[MyOtherTable] tab2
        ON tab1.ID = tab2.ID
```

Once the link is established, you can also use OPENQUERY to execute a SQL statement on the remote server and transfer only the data back to you. This can be a bit faster, and it will let the remote server optimize your query. If you cache the data in a temporary (or in-memory) table on DB1 in the example above, then you'll be able to query it just like joining a standard table. For example:

```
-- Fetch data from the other database server
SELECT *
INTO #myTempTable
FROM OPENQUERY([DB2], 'SELECT * FROM [MyDatabaseOnDB2].[dbo].[MyOtherTable]')

-- Now I can join my temp table to see the data
SELECT * FROM [MyDatabaseOnDB1].[dbo].[MyTable] tab1
    INNER JOIN #myTempTable tab2 ON tab1.ID = tab2.ID
```

Check out the documentation for OPENQUERY to see some more examples. The example above is pretty contrived. I would definitely use the first method in this specific example, but the second option using OPENQUERY can save some time and performance if you use the query to filter out some data.

Comment: And even more - enable ad hoc distributed queries on your mssql server and use connection string to oracle directly in openrowset or opendatasource https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187569.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Why not make two different calls to the database, one to the sql db and another to the oracle, after that inner join the data tables ?

```
DataTable oracleTbl = GetOracleData();
DataTable sqlTbl = GetSqlData();

var results = from oracleTbl in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                 join sqlTbl in dt2.AsEnumerable() on (Guid)sqlTbl ["ID"] equals (int)oracleTbl["ID"]
                 select new
                 {
                     //Select data you need
                 };
```